# htaccess Url rewriting not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with the Apache URL rewriting, 
I want when the user tapes an url like this : 
1 : `www.site.com/country/city/smthg`

or 2 : `www.site.com/country/city/smthg/fct`

or 3 : `www.site.com/country/city/smthg/fct/value`

I want to transform the url to this:

1 : `www.site.com/index.php/smthg/index/country/city`

2 : `www.site.com/index.php/smthg/fct/country/city`

3 : `www.site.com/index.php/smthg/fct/value/country/city`

I am using PHP Codeigniter framework,

I tried this but it is not working :

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ index.php/$3/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and in application->config->routes.php add routes like this

```
$route['country/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'ControllerName/functionName/$1/$2/$3';
```

Replace 'ControllerName' and 'functionName' with the actual names you have. $1, $2 and $3 becomes function parameters.

For details [CodeIgniter URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: For me Country and City are variables, and i have more than one controller

Comment: this worked for me:
`$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$3/index/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$3/$4/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$3/$4/$5/$1/$2';`
Thx ^^

Comment: We can use any number of routes. I always use explicit routes. If I have 3 controllers named a, b, c and want to hit the index function with 2 variables; one string and second integer. I will use:
    `$route['a/index/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'a/index/$1/$2';
    $route['b/index/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'b/index/$1/$2';
    $route['c/index/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'c/index/$1/$2';`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$3/index/$1/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$3/$4/$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$3/$4/$5/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```