# Web app with Codeigniter using IP address

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ip

I built a web app in Codeigniter and want to deploy it on a server that will only be for internal use. I can access it by an ip address 55.555.555.555/app but it gives me codeigniter's default 404 page even though I have a custom coded 404 page. I checked to make sure my htaccess file is working by creating an error and it is being read.  Currently I have the following code in my htaccess file next to my index.php.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R]
 </IfModule>
```

The server is running 14.04.1-Ubuntu not sure if that helps. Any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: what's your question? how to create a custom 404? or how to access the app?

Comment: If you are stuck in redirecting your app to 404 page, Have $route['404_override'] = 'controller/function_name' as a variable in config/routes.php.

Comment: I access it localhost/app/ but I uploaded it to the live server that will be using only and ip address(no domain name, its an internal app only)  so it should now be 44.494.494.494/app and I was hoping it would be a seamless transfer. When I visit that I am expecting my app to be there but I get a default 404 page. The reason I threw that in there was to let someone know I built a custom 404 page that is not being routed also but the codeigniter install is somewhat working.

Comment: Does it show 404 on localhost?

Comment: No, on my localhost it works fine.

Comment: So how does your webserver know which site you want to load? Is this CI installation your document root or default vhost? That's probably the problem...

Comment: Have you changed the `$base_url` value to the desired one in `config.php`?

Comment: @mgrueter Codeingiter will be the only thing on the server. I have it in a folder named file-system. I would assume I would access it by going to the ip/file-system/ and it would display my default controller and display the index function. On the server I have the / html / file-system. Are you thinking I need to move up a couple directories.

Comment: I changed the base_url to match the ip address. I talked with the IT guy that setup the server and he has ruled out it being an htaccess issues but couldn't figure out why its not working since he is not familiar with codeingiter and all the routing that takes place.  I am going to try here in a little while to upload it to a test server that actually has a domain name and such attached to it to make sure it works. It works great on my localhost so I am guessing it would be good otherwise or at least show an error.

Comment: Try placing a .htaccess file in your root folder, check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532856/htaccess-url-rewriting-not-working/32535685#32535685 if it still does not work, try placing a simple html file in the root directory (move index.php somewhere else) and check if you can access html page. If it still does not work there is some thing wrong with apache configuration.

Comment: @Scorpion, I placed the htaccess file at the root of the folder and added the lines in the link to it. / I placed an html file there and wrote some generic stuff in there and it worked. / Following mgrueters comment above I moved my app out of the file-system folder into the root directory and still nothing but the 404 page error.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback everyone! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: My base_url should be the ip address I am accessing correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access the app locally, use the local network ip(usually 192.xxx.xx.xx..) in your url, not the external one. If you use the external ip, you must forward a port, usually port 80, which is the default for web http protocol.

**EDIT:** And that's how you find your local ip on Ubuntu:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address